# JQuery: select rows in Threes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table like this:

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <th>h1</th>
      <th>h2</th>
      <th>h3</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
      some content here
  </tr>

  <tr>
      <td>1</td> <td>2</td> <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      inside this row, I have a table which contains 2 rows
  </tr>


   <tr>
      <td>1</td> <td>2</td> <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      inside this row, I have a table which contains 2 rows
  </tr>

   <tr>
      <td>1</td> <td>2</td> <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      inside this row, I have a table which contains 2 rows
  </tr>
  //it repeats like this


</table>
```

I'd like to apply alternative color for every 3 rows using jquery starting at the 3rd row, ie, I'd like the following section of code has alternative color. How to I do that? Thanks

```
      <tr>
         <td>1</td> <td>2</td> <td>3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          inside this row, I have a table which contains 2 rows
      </tr>
```

Basically, I don't want select header row and the first row after header row. after that, I want to select 3 rows each time, and give it an alternative color. The 3 rows will be the rows shown as above.

Comment: You mean you want to select (and change the color of) every row which contains exactly three <tr> cells? Your question isn't entirely clear.

Comment: NITYPICK: You should use thead and tbody elements.

Answer (score 2):

use the nth child selector

```
$("table tr:nth-child(3n)")
```

Comment: will that exclude the first 2 rows, the header row and "some content here" row?

Comment: Couldnt you have checked in the amount of time it took to type that?

Comment: it will only select the 3th row, not every 3 row

Comment: and with the edit only every 3 element, not start at the 3th, check my answer, 3n+3

Answer (score 1):

```
$('table tr:nth-child(3n) td').css('background-color', 'red');
$('table tr:nth-child(3n+1) td').css('background-color', 'blue');
$('table tr:nth-child(3n+2) td').css('background-color', 'green');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var totalOfRows = $('table').find('tr').length;

var rows = $('table').find('tr');

for(var i=0; i<totalOfRows;i++){
 $(rows[i]).attr('bgcolor','red'); //logical here
}

for example, yo can write .css('background-color', 'blue'); .css('background-color', 'pink'); etc
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use pure css3

```
table tr:nth-child(3n+3) { background:red; }
```

or via jquery too, like kmd97 answer

```
$("table tr:nth-child(3n+3)").css("background","red");
```

3n mean every 3 element, the +3 mean start at the 3th element.

you can try this [online css tester](http://css-tricks.com/examples/nth-child-tester/)